# SQLITE Many to Many Relationship Frequency Count

Tags: sql, sqlite, orm, subquery

I have three tables in a SQLITE database, call them Needle, NeedleHaystack and Haystack which are used in a many to many relationship join table.  I need to calculate the frequency for each unique item in needle, how often it appears in each unique Haystack (percentage would be preferrable, count would be acceptable).

```
  Needle          NeedleHaystack                    Haystack
  +----+-------+  +----+-----------+-------------+  +----+-------+
  | id | value |  | id | needle_id | haystack_id |  | id | value |
  +----+-------+  +----+-----------+-------------+  +----+-------+
  |  1 |  foo1 |  | 1  |    1      |     7       |  | 7  |  bar7 |
  |  2 |  foo2 |  | 2  |    1      |     8       |  | 8  |  bar8 |
  |  3 |  foo3 |  | 3  |    1      |     9       |  | 9  |  bar9 |
  +----+-------+  | 4  |    2      |     7       |  +----+-------+
                  +----+-----------+-------------+
```

Such that we end up with a result like this

```
  +-----------+--------------------------+
  | needle_id | frequency_over_haystacks |
  +-----------+--------------------------+
  |    1      |          100%            | // needle id 1 appears in 100% of Haystacks
  |    2      |           33%            | // needle id 2 appears in 33% of Haystacks
  |    3      |            0%            | // needle id 3 appears in no Haystacks
  +-----------+--------------------------+ // on and on, for each needle that may be present...
```

Comment: Why is the percentage for needle 1 not 100%?

Comment: Good catch, fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you basically want aggregation:

```
select n.needle_id, count(distinct nh.haystack_id) * 1.0 / h.cnt
from needle n left join
     needlehaystack nh
     on n.needle_id = nh.needle_id cross join
     (select count(*) as cnt from haystack) h
group by n.needle_id, h.cnt;
```

This allows duplicates in `needlehaystack`.  If those are not allowed, then use `count(*)` rather than `count(distinct)` in the `select`.

Comment: Could you go a little more into your comment about duplicates?  I think that you've hit the nail on the head but I want to make sure I understand what you mean.  I THINK I do, but I want to make sure that you're just saying if there are duplicate rows with the same needle_id and haystack_id and I don't want them to be counted multiple times, use `count(*) * 1.0 / h.cnt` as opposed to `count(distinct nh.haystack_id) * 1.0 / h.cnt`

Comment: Also, will the result be the actual percentage or the decimal version?  E.g. `.35` or `35.0`

Comment: @MichaelScott . . . This returns a ratio between 0 and 1.  If you want a percentage, multiply by 100.0 rather than 1.0.  Your observation about duplicates is correct.  This counts them only once.